# How can i validate that my module must worked only allowed domain

Tags: magento2, secure

I want to validate my module only work with allowed domain in magento2

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism for that in Magento and the only reliable way is to build in a check that you do everywhere your module does something (like, in a `isEnabled()` method) and encrypt the source code, because otherwise anybody could remove the check.

There is a heavy discussion if encrypted source is tolerable or not, I'd personally not use any encrypted extension, and you *will* lose customers. On the other hand you prevent piracy, so you might gain more than you lose.

You could also take a middle ground, build in the check without encrypting the module. This will be easy to break, if someone is willing to do so, but it takes basic development skills and malicious intent, so it should help *a little*.